# Perl: can you make a "use"d module or setting apply to the including script?

Tags: perl

For example, every single one of my scripts has this at the top:

```
use warnings; use strict; use v5.10;
use Tools;
```

My "Tools" package has a bunch of functions that I use all the time. I would rather just include it and have it use warnings, strict, and 5.10 for the including script, since I have to `use` those for every script anyway. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Most passable editors have a built in templating system.  Have you tried approaching the problem from that angle?

Comment: Alternatively you could look at the source of `Modern::Perl` for the techniques used there...

Comment: My editor is generally vim, but I script in many different environments and I was hoping for something editor-agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into) with a custom `import` method to turn stuff on in the importing class. For example:

```
package Tools;

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';

use Import::Into;

sub import {
    my $target = caller;
    strict->import::into( $target );
    warnings->import::into( $target );
    feature->import::into( $target, ':5.10' );

    # other imports, etc
}
```

I wrote a more detailed post about using Import::Into here: [Removing Perl Boilerplate with Import::Into](http://friedo.com/blog/2014/06/removing-boilerplate-with-importinto).